# Does Langchain’s `create_csv_agent` and `create_pandas_dataframe_agent` functions work with non-OpenAl LLMs

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, llama

Does Langchain's `create_csv_agent` and `create_pandas_dataframe_agent` functions work with non-OpenAl LLM models too like Llama
2 and Vicuna? The only example I have seen in the documentation (in the links below) are only using OpenAI API.

`create_csv_agent`:
https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/toolkits/csv

`create_pandas_dataframe_agent`:
https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/toolkits/pandas

Would really appreciate ANY input on this. Many thanks!

Comment: _the functionalities highlighted are generic for all LLM types_ - https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/models/llms/

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this link for loading models from HuggingFace hub
https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/llms/huggingface_hub

After that you can put the model in the agent this way

```
from langchain.llms import HuggingFaceHub
import os
os.environ["HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN"] = HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN
repo_id = "google/flan-t5-xxl"
llm = HuggingFaceHub(
        repo_id=repo_id, model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.5, "max_length": 64})

agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(llm,
                                      df,
                                      verbose=True,
                                      max_iterations =10,
                                      include_df_in_prompt = False,
                                      )
```